# Мониторинг подключений к серверу на Java

Tags: java, linux, сервер

Мне нужно чтобы программа получала список всех IP адресов, обращающихся к моему серверу, и я мог получить этот список. Работаю в линуксовом терминале. Ещё желательно чтобы программа могла блокировать подключения с определённых адресов.

Comment: Посмотрите исходники `tail` и разберите бекенд `iptables`.
И покажите ваш код, который написали.
P.S. "Линуксового терминала" не существует. Виртуальная консоль, псевдотерминальное устройство или эмулятор терминала.

Comment: С блокировкой вопрос можно решить и по другому. Можно сделать файл с списком ip для блокировки. программа должна время от времени его читать (или использовать inotify). Это даст возможность гибко блокировать пользователей (например, показывать им специальное сообщение)

Answer (score 1):

> Мне нужно чтобы программа получала список всех IP адресов,
>   обращающихся к моему серверу

Показать все входящие интернет подключения:

```
sudo netstat -l -A inet
```

То же, но только для TCP соедиенений:

```
sudo netstat -l -tcp -A inet
```

Comment: Это не на Java. Да и вопрос с блокировкой остаётся открытым.

Comment: @Sergey Gornostaev **Это не на Java**. Но это на linux... Неужели на Java нет некотрого аналога функции *system()* ?!